# Number of functions from `float64` to `float64`

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics

Let's say that we want to know how many functions there are that map a single float64 number to another float64 number, and that this map is defined in such a way that all possible float64 numbers are in its domain. Since float64 numbers are represented with 64 binary digits (bits), there should be $2^{64}$ possible values in the domain and $2^{64}$ possible values in the function's range.

This should entail $\left({2^{64}}\right)^{2^{64}}$ possible functions, which can be simplified somewhat to $2^{1180591620717411303424}$.

Going a step further, if I wished to map a vector of dimension $n$ of floats to another vector of dimension $m$ of floats, would this be $\left({2^{64 m}}\right)^{2^{64n}}$?

Comment: Is every 64 bit sequence a valid float64? Or are some representations forbidden by the format? Also your nesting of exponents is wrong, the number of functions from a domain with $m$ elements to a codomain with $n$ elements is $n^m$, so there are parentheses involved when $n$ is written as $2^k$.

Comment: @Ian Good question! I will look that up.

Comment: To avoid that issue, we could say `uint64` instead.

Comment: Note that $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$, which is different from $a^{(b^c)}$. The number of functions from the set of $64n$-bit strings to the set of $64m$-bit strings is $(2^{64m})^{(2^{64n})}=2^{(64m\times2^{64n})}$.

Comment: For the number of valid patterns in IEEE 754 you can check this link https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=984141